# iOS freehand drawing with orientation support

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm using this (https://github.com/acerbetti/ACEDrawingView) sample code in my freehand drawing application. I'm having a problem with orientation changes. Suppose if i draw a circle in portrait and change the orientation to landscape the circle, changes to oval and similarly square changes to rectangle.

[image]

[image]

This happens since, the drawing is rendered to an image and that images is assigned to an imageview which act as a canvas.
Problem:-
In landscape the image expands horizontally

I tried setting the content mode to AspectFit, it work on orientation changes but when i draw again it get screwed up.

Could you please guide me with this or is there any other approach that i can work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what i've concluded.

Increase the height w.r.t to width scale. So, the object remains the same.i.e., square as square and circle as circle.